# How to use alternative name for Gruntfile.js?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Is there a way to rename Gruntfile.js itself? Is there are syntax for using an alternatively named Gruntfile.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://gruntjs.com/using-the-cli

> --gruntfile
>
> Specify an alternate Gruntfile.
>
> By default, grunt looks in the current or parent directories for the
>   nearest Gruntfile.js or Gruntfile.coffee file.

Answer (score 1):

Just use option `--gruntfile` in which you can specify the alternative name

Full documentation is available on http://gruntjs.com/using-the-cli